# Ford Fiesta 2010 P1934 Pending VEHICLE SPEED SIGNAL

Tags: ford, cel, fiesta

Ford Fiesta 2010 P1934 Pending VEHICLE SPEED SIGNAL  .Pls advise what is P1934 and it it's possible cause.  TQ

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Ford DTC P1934](https://www.dtcdecode.com/Ford/P1934)

> This DTC sets when there is a sudden loss of vehicle speed signal over a period of time. Vehicle speed data is received from either the transmission control module (TCM) or the anti-lock brake system (ABS) module.

...etc.

And here is [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mDMrmqKU4Do).